# Ionic 4 : how to make a File (@ionic-native/file) from camera(@ionic-native/camera) FILE_URI

Tags: file, ionic-framework, native

1. I tried to make a file(@ionic-native/file) from camera(@ionic-native/camera) FILE_URI(videoUri) using window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL().
2. But It does not work!!!: Maybe I need to use another API.
3. The following block is my code:

   ```
   let options: CameraOptions = {
       quality: 50,
       destinationType:     this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,               
       sourceType:this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
       allowEdit: false,
       mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.VIDEO,
       saveToPhotoAlbum: false};

   this.camera.getPicture(options)
       .then((videoUri)=> {

          window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(videoUri, function (fileEntry) {
               fileEntry.file(function (fileObj) {
                   this.auth.presentAlert(fileObj)
                   this.startTransfering(fileObj) ;
                   console.log("Size = " + fileObj.size);
               });
           });
       },
       (err)=> {
            this.auth.presentAlert(err) ;
       }) ;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

**here is the correct usage:**

`mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE`

```js
let options: CameraOptions = {
    quality: 50,
    destinationType:     this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,               
    sourceType:this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    allowEdit: false,
    mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: false};

this.camera.getPicture(options)
    .then((videoUri)=> {

       window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(videoUri, function (fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.file(function (fileObj) {
                this.auth.presentAlert(fileObj)
                this.startTransfering(fileObj) ;
                console.log("Size = " + fileObj.size);
            });
        });
    },
    (err)=> {
         this.auth.presentAlert(err) ;
    }) ;
```

Comment: I need a pickup video-file from camera photo/video library. I can pick-up a video using a camera.getPicture(), but I cannot get a native file from the URI...

Comment: I don't think the camera plugin is the way to go. Try using file chooser instead. It's as simple as doing: `fileChooser.open().then(uri => console.log(uri)).catch(e => console.log(e));` provided you've installed the file chooser plugin.

Comment: I tested to pick up a video using camera.getPicture() like above example. Selecting a video is OK, but I cannot send the video file(FILE_URI) to my server using Flow.js API.

Comment: If your use case involves sending to a server, the [File Transfer plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer/) would do the job.

Comment: I have also tried to upload using @ionic-native/FileTransfer, but I can't do it. (Nothing happens when trying to upload) Maybe I am misusing the API about File. And then I want to use Flow.js for uploading because of simultaneous multi-chunk uploading of a big file.